# Memory management when changing src for ImageView

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, imageview

I am still new to Android, and never had to deal with memory management in my previous experience.
In my android application, I have an activity with a TextView, a ListView, and ImageView.  I have listeners for the textview and listview, and the code that changes the contents in all three of those views.  The contents is stored in the arraylist.  The source for the ImageView is stored in form of a String (filenames), and the code that makes the changes looks like this:

```
        tv1.setText(myText);
        imgView.setImageResource(myImage);
```

This worked perfectly well while I only had a few images to test the logic, but once I added more images, I started to get the OutOfMemory error.  If I make the images smaller, I get that error a little later in the process, but I still get it.
At first, I thought that Android does not release the previous source, so I thought using recycle() before the reassignment will help.  Instead, I've got another error when I try to change the source:

> Cannot draw recycled bitmaps

It looks like I am missing some vital understanding about how the ImageView handles the source images. Does it assign the bitmap reference and then keeps the same reference, but somehow changes content?

Then, after reading [this](http://wip.org/blog/android-memory-reduce-reuse-recycle/) article, I realized I have a different kind of problem altogether, the one that might be solved by using the inBitmap.  Yet, the documentation says the bitmaps have to be the same size for that, and mine are not.
I am thinking of converting my drawable to bitmap, then scaling it to some hard-coded dimensions, then using inBitmap.  I guess my second question is - does this approach make sense?  Are there any downfalls in scaling the images? And any examples would be appreciated, of course.
Thank you!